# Is this Decathlon Cobra bike (frame) unique?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

So last summer I got a job in a workshop, during which I had the opportunity to build my own road bike from a Decathlon frame. The model is apparently a **Cobra Special** (as shown on the pictures). For your information, when I started working and riding on it, both wheels where yellow (one broke 6 months ago).

Here is the additional (original) information I have :

- Wheels are 700x23C ;
- Can accept up to a 3x7 transmission ;
- Had a **cassette**, before it broke during a ride ;
- Probably produced between 1990 and 2000 ;
- Cobra had several submodels such as (most websites are in French) : [500](https://www.saikle.fr/produits/decathlon-course-cobra-500-triple-plateau1636143282174), [560](https://www.saikle.fr/produits/decathlon-velo-decathlon-cobra-cintre-ville1622566453651), [700](https://www.velovintageagogo.com/t13256-decathlon-cobra-700), [720](https://www.velovintageagogo.com/t15504-decathlon-cobra-720), [740](https://www.miraclesparis.fr/product-page/v%C3%A9lo-d%C3%A9cathlon-cobra-740-sur-base-vitus-792), etc.

On the pics, only the front wheel, the frame and the fork are original. All additional piece or equipment is either taken from other bikes (handlebars, back wheel, and few others), new, or personal.[image: Whole bike] [image: Brand and model] [image: Submodel]

This post is certainly not an emergency, it's just about curiosity. Of course, any help identifying the bike's origin (or finding any related document, data, forums, etc.) would be highly appreciated, but it's not a problem if no one knows. :)

Thanks in advance, and have a lovely day !

Comment: So your question is "why is it called `special` ?"

Comment: Yes @Criggie. And is it 'just' (by the name) a "Cobra Special", or is it a "Cobra 500 Special" or "560 Special" or "720 Special", etc. ? And I'm also interested about any original data and/or document

Comment: Did you try contacting decathlon? I know it is a lazy answer but since the company is still around, there is a chance that product information still exists or they can forward it to somebody from their bicycle brand to identify the frame/model.

Comment: @DoNuT: yes I did by phone, and they told me to send an email with the maximum of information I already have (pictures, data). I'm waiting for an answer right now, and might edit my question to give the information I received from them (for whoever could be interested in it).

Comment: @Marck Good luck! I mentioned that because I have a early-2000s Fondriest frame (from the brand of a 90s Italian pro cyclist). A couple of years ago I also wanted to figure out what exact model it is. Took a while but even though the brand was sold, I got an email back from Maurizio stating year and model ... even though he didn't tell my much more than written on the frame, only that it is a 2004/05 model and no production numbers or price. You often just don't have access to old documents because nobody cares about your business 20 years ago.